# Mismatching return type error in ternary operator, swift

Tags: ios, swift, ternary-operator

I wrote a ternary statement in Swift, and in both cases of the statement I'm setting the property of a tableview cell to one string or another, like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let item = items.allItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    indexPath.row == items.allItems.count ? cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "" : cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"
    return cell
}
```

However I end up with this error:  "Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '()?' and 'String?'"

I don't understand why there's a type mismatch here- I'm doing the exact same thing in both cases of the statement. Could someone shed some light on this? Thanks

Comment: you are doing an assign at the right of the `?` operator: `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""` I guess

Comment: I'm doing an assign in both cases, the only difference is which string I assign the property to

Comment: The point of the ternary operator is that it returns one of two values.  In Swift an assignment doesn't really return a value which is why it is returning void (aka `()`).  So, you're using the ternary operator wrong.

Comment: Instead you should do `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = indexPath.row == items.allItems.count ? "" : "$\(item.valueInDollars)"`

Comment: In fact the issue here is the attempt to assign a value in the left and right part of the ternary expression, that is the reason of the `()?` error.

Comment: Ohhh I see I see... makes perfect sense. Thanks everyone!